# Youtube responds super slow to keyboard shortcuts, but it responds fast to mouse commands

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, youtube

I just did a fresh install of Win10 on a new SSD. Everything is running fine, but Youtube, for some reason, when I use the keyboard to pause, raise the volume, skip forward or back, takes around 500/700ms to respond, making my video viewing experience bothersome.

What could I test to troubleshoot this? This happens on all browsers (tested on Firefox, Chrome and Edge [though it's chromium]).

I've resorted to downloading the videos and watching them on MPC-HC or VLC.

Comment: First thing I'd try is set your power management to high performance. By default it is set to balanced, and in recent versions of Windows, high performance profile is removed, you have to first create a new profile using the high performance template, then switch to it.

Comment: I just did that. No apparent changes. I just noticed that the keyboard has the same delay when typing on the Youtube search bar. It seems the Keypress event has a few hundred ms delay for some reason only on that website on any browser.

Comment: How is your internet connection/wifi? Is it up to speed? It may be that any interaction is delayed because it connects to the internet while doing so. You can test this out by loading the youtube page, then disconnect your entire network, then type text to search. If it is a network issue, it should now go instant.

Comment: I was going to respond to you but then it fixed itself. I waited a day to see if it went back but nope. I can't debug now because it's fixed. My wifi is great, speedy through Ethernet. I'd like to test further but it's working perfectly now. Weird stuff!